# Different urls mapping to the same xhtml file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

With jsf 2.x I want to use urls like

```
../admin1.xhtml  
../admin2.xhtml  
../admin3.xhtml
```

that should all call the same xhtml file (generic.xhtml), but with a parameter like this:

```
../generic.xhtml?page=admin1  
../generic.xhtml?page=admin2  
../generic.xhtml?page=admin3
```

instead of creating a lot of useless identical xhtml files to serve the requests. How can i better achieve that with jsfs? Am i bound to write loads of xml or can i make a simple rule in faces-config.xml, or should i use some other tools?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) url prettyfier. First of all it'll allow you removing your file extensions, which is considered a best practice (you would be able to change your backend framework without altering the urls themselves).

Apart from that, there's the chance to integrate the parameter itself into the url:

```
<!-- Maps "/admin/#{page}" to the URL "/generic.xhtml?page=value" -->
<url-mapping id="admin-view">
    <pattern value="/admin/#{page}" />
    <view-id value="/generic.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

So you'll be able to type:

```
/admin/admin1
```

And that will drive you to:

```
/generic.xhtml?page=admin1
```